# wrapAll not working with array of objects

Tags: jquery, object, word-wrap

I am writing a script which

1. takes elements
2. splits those elements into smaller sub-arrays
3. wraps those sub arrays with a `<div>`

I have this working:

```
var elems = $('p');

content = [];
temp = [];

for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var elem = elems[i];
    temp.push(elem);
    if (i === 2 || i+1 === elems.length) {
        content.push(temp);
        temp = [];
    }
};

console.log(content);

$.each(content, function(i) {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.wrapAll($('<div class="wrapper"></div>'));
});
```

[see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TJMpP/2/) 
This uses an object containing the elements

However, when I return jQuery objects instead of just elements, the `wrapAll()` function suddenly breaks, throwing a TypeError: `Value does not implement interface Node.` while other functions (replacing wrapAll) don't break (like wrap() or wrapInner()).

Code:

```
var elems = $('p');

content = [];
temp = [];

for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var elem = $(elems[i]);
    temp.push(elem);
    if (i === 2 || i+1 === elems.length) {
        content.push(temp);
        temp = [];
    }
};

console.log(content);

$.each(content, function(i) {
    $(this).wrapAll($('<div class="wrapper"></div>'));
});
```

See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TJMpP/3/) (fiddle throws another TypeError: context is undefined, but I think that is due to the way jsfiddle works with frames).

Am I perhaps approaching this wrong? But shouldn't the wrapAll work? (replace it with wrap() in the second Fiddle, and that will work)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var elems = $('p').get();

content = [];
temp = [];

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var elem = elems[i];
    temp.push(elem);
    if (i === 2 || i + 1 === elems.length) {
        content.push(temp);
        temp = [];
    }
};

console.log(content);

$.each(content, function (i) {
    $(this).wrapAll($('<div class="wrapper"></div>'));
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TJMpP/4/)

Also, you see this: [**DEMO USING SLICE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TJMpP/5/)

Comment: Thanks for the example (and the slice demo), but I need the element to be a jQuery object *inside* the for() loop, as I need to modify and read out data there. Sorry if this was unclear in my question. Any ideas?

Comment: To be more specific: I need to repeat (add it to the temp object twice) an element when the for loop creates a new 'temp' object and pushes everything to the content object. The only way I know how to do this is clone() the element, but that won't work unless it is a jquery object, that's where I'm stuck

Comment: Using JavaScript object instead of jQuery object as array elements helped.